# Select the SECOND LAST record in each group

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group, mysql-workbench, dml, sqlyog

There is a table `Remark` that contains data as shown below:

```
       SerialNo | RemarkNo  | Desp
=============================================
             10 |         1 | rainy
             10 |         2 | sunny
             11 |         1 | sunny
             11 |         2 | rainy
             11 |         3 | cloudy
             11 |         4 | sunny
             12 |         1 | rainy
```

What query will return the following result:

```
             10 |         1 | rainy
             11 |         3 | cloudy
             12 |      null | null
```

That is, the second last record in each group should be returned?

Assuming all the RemarkNo for a SerialNo are continuous. The larger the remark number, the later the remark was made. Hence, the second last RemarkNo for SerialNo 10 is 1 with Desp 'rainy'.

Comment: SELECT r1.*
FROM remark r1 LEFT JOIN remark r2
 ON (r1.serial_no = r2.serial_no 
 AND r1.remark_no < r2.remark_no)
WHERE r2.remark_no IS NULL; -- this return me the last record

Comment: Shouldn't it return `10|1|Sunny`?

Comment: @KevinBowersox added my assumption in my question.

Comment: See if this question helps: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1895110/1275871.  If so, you can sort the table in descending RemarkNo then keep the second row for each SerialNo.  Easy in DBs that support ROW_NUMBER window function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
select s.SerialNo, r.RemarkNo, r.Desp
from (select SerialNo, max(RemarkNo) maxRemark from Remark group by SerialNo) s
left join Remark r on s.SerialNo = r.SerialNo and s.maxRemark-1 = r.RemarkNo
```

([SQLFiddle here.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d2cd5/1))

Comment: Thank you, Mark. I have edited your SQLFiddle a little bit to make it more readable for myself. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d2cd5/4

Answer (score 0):

Here is some sql pseudo-code to get you started:

```
select
  penultimate.*
from data as penultimate
left join (
  /* query on data to return last row frome each group */
) as ultimate
  on /* sql to join 2nd last record on each group to last group */
where not ultimate.SerialNo is null
```

Answer (score 0):

Completely ineffective solution, but works ...

```
SELECT
  SerialNo,
  RemarkNo,
  (SELECT Desp
   FROM Remarks
   WHERE SerialNo = r3.SerialNo AND RemarkNo = r3.RemarkNo) Desp
FROM (
  SELECT
      r.SerialNo,
      (SELECT r2.RemarkNo
       FROM Remarks r2
       WHERE r.SerialNo = r2.SerialNo
       ORDER BY r2.RemarkNo DESC
       LIMIT 1, 1) RemarkNo
  FROM (SELECT DISTINCT SerialNo FROM Remarks) r) r3
```

Working example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a1f89/22