# Select the second last record in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1064

I need get the second last record of `DATE` with Google Column but is impossible because the query very complex.

I tried "-1" on any piece of query and nothing

```
SELECT d.dominio AS dominio_dominio,
    p.palavra AS palavras_palavra,
    rm.posicao_google AS google,
    rm.verificado AS verificao_robo,
    rm.usuario AS rank_dono,
p.id AS id_palavra
FROM rank_monitor rm
JOIN dominio d ON d.id = rm.dominio
JOIN palavras p ON p.id = rm.palavras
LEFT JOIN rank_monitor rm1 ON rm1.dominio = rm.dominio
    AND rm1.palavras = rm.palavras
    AND rm1.verificado > rm.verificado
WHERE rm1.id IS NULL
    AND rm.usuario = '35'
GROUP BY rm.palavras-1
ORDER BY rm.posicao_google ASC
```

How can I give the second last result Google column?

I saw the question [Select the SECOND LAST record in each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15453231/select-the-second-last-record-in-each-group) but not solve.

Comment: You want last column then use reverse order with limit i.e. ORDER DESC with LIMIT 1,1

Comment: Provide sample data and expected results.

Comment: [link](http://postimg.org/image/ozyztw0f7/)

Comment: i have the image, how i post the sql ? sqlfindlle are down. thanks :)

Comment: i store the sql on [SQL STRUCTURE](https://jsfiddle.net/4cfe5w48/)

Comment: @BrunoPinna Please use **http://sqlfiddle.com/**